# List sharing in OCaml

Tags: list, ocaml

I'am curious about memory management in OCaml. When lists are shared through the program invocation. As example:

```
let rec insertAux v acc l =
   match l with
   | [] -> acc 
   | h::t -> insertAux v ((v::h) :: acc) t;;

let insert v l = insertAux v l l;;
let rec sublist l = 
   match l with
   | [] -> [[]]
   | head::tail ->  insert head (sublist tail);;
```

What elements/lists, in insertAux, are copied or shared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I can tell, what will be shared and where, I need to ensure, that we have a common definition of the word "share". I would propose the following definition: "A value is shared between two data structures iff they both contain a pointer to that value".

Let first look at the `insertAux` function, that takes three values and produces the resulting value. So, let's infer the sharing relation between input values and the result. If `l` is empty, then there is no sharing between `v` and `result`, and no sharing between `l` and result. Finally, `acc` value is 100% shared with the result. So these two values are the same.

This was the simple, base case. Now let's look at the induction step:

```
| h::t -> insertAux v ((v::h) :: acc) t
```

Let's bind intermediate values to names, so that we can easily refer them in the text:

```
| h::t -> 
  let vh = v :: h in
  let vhacc = vh :: acc in 
  let result = insertAux v vhacc t in
  result
```

The `vh` value will share values with both `v` and `h`. To create `vh` OCaml will allocate a new linked list node, that is a pair of pointers. One pointer will reference `v`, and another will reference to `h`. Value `vhacc` will share values with `vh` and `acc`. Since, the sharing relation is transitive, it means, that it will share values with `v`, `h` and `acc`. Internally, a it will create a pair of pointers, with one pointing to `vh` and another to `acc`. By induction, the `result` will share `v`, `h` and `t`.

To summarize, `insertAux` will build a new value, that will share all components of the input values. It will allocate `2*N` nodes to connect shared values in a new way, where `N` is a length of the list `l`.

Function `let insert v l = insertAux v l l` will produce a value, that will share both input values. It will create a list, that will contain a duplicate of list `l`, and `N` lists which will contain a pointer to `v` as a head, and duplicates of `l` as the tail.

Finally, function sublist, will produce a value, that will share its inputs. It will create a list, that will contain `N+1` elements, where each element will be a subset of the original list, freshely built from the components (that are shared) of the input list.

To summarize, OCaml will share all values. If values have mutable fields, then it may impose problems. If they are immutable, then it is absolutely transparent (i.e., invisible, doesn't affect the semantics, etc) to a programmer, and one can reason about them like they are always copied, and every new constructor will create a totally new value without sharing if it makes things easier. In fact, sharing has a meaning only for mutable data structures. Moreover, further compiler optimizations, like Common Subexpression Elimination (CLE) may find even more opportunities for the sharing. There are other optimization techniques, that may reuse existing values, and mutate them in place, if it is possible to prove, that they are unused in other parts of the program (although, to my knowledge, currently OCaml doesn't perform this optimization).

One more thing to know. OCaml represents values uniformly, either as a word if a value can fit into a word, or as a pointer to the heap-allocated value if it can't. Basically, it means, that all values, that can fit into OCaml word will be unboxed (e.g., ints, nullary constructors, chars, etc).

Comment: yeah, indeed, it looks like that I've copied your definitions incorrectly into my interpreter. Your implementation is fine :)

Comment: in explaination of my question - i got task for my classes to implement powerset function that doesnt produce any trash

Comment: Aha, now it is clear, why you have passed `l` into `insertAux` as an accumulator. Yeah, then indeed, your function will not produce any garbage.